# Flutter: how to print the server error "Connection was refused by the server." using dio and NodeJs based backend

Tags: node.js, flutter, authentication, response, dio

I am trying to show the message of **Connection was refused by the server.** in popup when user is trying to login but when server is not running so then it shows this message.

here is my login code

```
Future login() async {
    try{
    Dio dio=new Dio();
    var data={
      'username': user.username,
      'password': user.password,
      'date':formattedDate
    };
    await dio
    .post(localhostUrlLogin,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse) async {

      });} catch(e){
        print("error "+e.response.statusCode.toString());  
        print(OSError.noErrorCode);  // return -1 
      }}}
```

i  am trying to  getting  statuscode  but its is returning  this

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'statusCode' was called on null.
E/flutter (25521): Receiver: null
E/flutter (25521): Tried calling: statusCode
```

i used  on DioError  catch(e)  but it is  returning  the same error.

here is my login backend code

```
login = (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ "username": req.body.username }, function (err, data) {

    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json("unspecified name")
      return;
    }
   else {
      if (data.length <= 0) {
        res.status(400).json({
          "message": "Invalid Input!"
        })
      }
      else {
        //bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,data[0].password).then(function(result) {
        var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data[0].password, 'my-secret-key@123');
        var decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
        if (req.body.password == decryptedData) {
          
          var token = jwt.sign({
            data: 'foobar'
          }, 'secret', { expiresIn: "30 minute" })
          
          console.log(req.body.date)
          User.find({ "username": req.body.username, "Date": req.body.date }, function (err, value) {
            if (err) {
              res.status(400).json("unspecified name")
              return;
            }
            else{
            let timein = false

            if (value.length>0) {
              timein = true;
            }
            res.status(200).json({ auth: true, AccessToken: token, User: data[0], timeinStatus: timein, data: value})
          }
          })
 
          //res.status(200).json({auth: true,  AccessToken:token,  User:data[0], timeIn: timein}) 
        }
        else {
          res.status(300).json({
            "message": "Input!"
          })
        }

        //  });

      }
    }
  })
}
module.exports = login;
```

please help is anyone know how to do this .

Comment: Replace this print("error "+e.response.statusCode.toString());  with print("error "+e.toString());.

Comment: it is printing this DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 192.168.1.101, port = 59998

Comment: but how can i add this to if checks and prints the pop up accordingly

Comment: Checkout this https://dev.to/ashishrawat2911/handling-network-calls-and-exceptions-in-flutter-54me

If error is DioError and error.type == DioErrorType.other, then handle this case.